# Behavior of np.take with Boolean arrays

Tags: python, numpy, boolean-indexing

`np.take` is a function that takes the elements from an array along an axis. When there is an axis parameter specified it behaves exactly like "fancy" indexing (indexing using arrays), but without an axis parameter the array a is flattened, and then the indices taken from this array. However, the documentation gives nothing on `boolean` indexing and it is unspecified what the behavior is with boolean arrays: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html

The code in question is the following

Input:

```
a = np.array([2, 3])
b = np.array([[False,  True],
              [ True, False],
              [False,  True],
              [ True, False]])

a.take(b)
```

Output:

```
array([[2, 3],
       [3, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 2]])
```

In this particular code how is the output being switched when we have a column of [True, False] and stays the same with a column of [False, True]? Now when I try this with `boolean` indexing where I have the index as a `boolean` array I get an error:

Input:

```
a = np.array([2, 3])
b = np.array([[False,  True],
              [ True, False],
              [False,  True],
              [ True, False]])

a[b]
```

Output:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-8b64b196a893> in <cell line: 7>()
      5               [ True, False]])
      6 
----> 7 a[b]

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

This error makes sense to me because the index array (b) has two dimensions while the array a has only one. So what is `np.take` doing so that it just switches the columns in each row?

Comment: I believe `take` doesn't implement boolean indexing. The first example is treated as integer array indexing, along the lines of `a[b.astype(int)]`

Comment: Hello Brain,

Oh, so you are saying that the b array would basically be treated as:

b = np.array([[0,  1],
                     [ 1, 0],
                     [0,  1],
                     [ 1, 0]])

and it would take the indices?

Comment: It sure looks that way, doesn't it?  The returned values are consistent with alternating 0/1 indexing.

Comment: `take` is most useful when the array has many (>2) dimensions, and you want to index without a awkward mix of slices and ellipses.  Or if you want to take advantage of the wrap or clip modes.  In sum, some sort of code generated indices.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation, it is mentioned that " If indices is not one dimensional, the output also has these dimensions.", So the output will be in the shape of indices.
The True and False in array 'b' act as 1 and 0 respectively, i.e. index 1 and 0. So if I replace it with this value, I get the same output.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2, 3])
#b = np.array([[False,  True],
#              [ True, False],
#              [False,  True],
#              [ True, False]])
b = np.array([[0,  1],
              [ 1, 0],
              [0,  1],
              [ 1, 0]])              

c = a.take(b)
print(c)
```

> output

```
[[2 3]
 [3 2]
 [2 3]
 [3 2]]
```

And if add a value , say '3' in the array b, will get 'IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2'. Because size of a is 2.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2, 3])
b = np.array([[True,  True],
              [ False, 3]])              


c = a.take(b)
print(c)
```

> output

```
    c = a.take(b)
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```